# Placing java-created ImageView next to another java-created ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a feature which allows users to tap a button, which brings them to their SD card. When the user selects a picture, it returns to the screen with the button and displays the picture in an `ImageView`. If the user taps the button again, it returns the user to the gallery. When the user selects a picture this time, it should appear TO THE RIGHT OF the first `ImageView`. I've read through pretty much every answer there is on this subject and tried everything. Somehow I seem to try everything "that works perfectly" and yet it does not work for me somehow. Every time, I place the first picture and it appears in the top left corner and then I place the second and it just appears on top of the first one.  What am I doing wrong? Please tell me I'm dumb and just need to (fill in the blank). Here's my code:

```
public class PictureSelector extends Activity {

    final int PIC_CODE = 12345;
    int picCounter = 0;
    ImageView[] imgViewArray = new ImageView[10];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_selector);
        Button bGallery = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bGallery);
        bGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PIC_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        if (requestCode == PIC_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(imageStream);

                if (picCounter == 0) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            100, 100);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,
                            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                    imgViewArray[picCounter] = new ImageView(
                            PictureSelector.this);
                    imgViewArray[picCounter].setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                    imgViewArray[picCounter].setId(picCounter);
                    this.addContentView(imgViewArray[picCounter], layoutParams);
                    picCounter++;
                } else {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            100, 100);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                            imgViewArray[picCounter - 1].getId());
                    imgViewArray[picCounter] = new ImageView(
                            PictureSelector.this);
                    imgViewArray[picCounter].setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                    imgViewArray[picCounter].setId(picCounter);
                    this.addContentView(imgViewArray[picCounter], layoutParams);
                    picCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the XML, in case it's relevant:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlGallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="Gallery" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'd start by adding a horizontal LinearLayout below that Button, and then just add/remove views from it.  Have you tired this already?

Comment: have you try whit Linear Layout?

Comment: i tried a linear layout, but that didn't work for me either.  also, i thought relative.  also, it seems to me that a relative layout would be more suitable for my needs since it "Enables you to specify the location of child objects relative to each other (child A to the left of child B) or to the parent (aligned to the top of the parent)." i will try julian's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
Here you MUST read about different types of layouts

Comment: ok, i read this page.  what am i meant to take from this other than general info on layouts?  which part was supposed to give me the "aha"?

Comment: ah, maybe grid view is the way to go.  going to try that out!

Comment: grid is good for picture display, u can customize android:numColumns="2" etc, Don`t forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: the "aha" u can get when you understand how relativelayout is working :)

Comment: what specifically is it that you're referring to that will help me understand what i'm missing with relative layouts?  i thought relative layouts were better for the operation i'm trying to carry out.  from what i understand about relative layouts, my code looks fine.  anything more specific in regards to relative layouts that i should be looking for?

Comment: RelativeLayout is more complex and give more opportunities. If u understand how every layout type is working u can make any design whit different layout types combination. In your case i will choose GridView, his purpose is to display images in grid, u can set column numbers etc. But you need to be more experiences whit java, becouse image need to be reconfigured properly before you put them in ImageView. If you don`t configure them they will look strange, and different in size, it will be a mess!